# Finding content by name in Vue test cases

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, jestjs

I'm testing my function testValue

```
    import expectedView from './directory'
    it('testing testValue', async () => {
    dialog = shallowMount(Dialog, {
        propsData: {
            data: data,
        }
    });
    dialog.vm.testValue("25");
    const expectedView = await dialog.find(expectedView);
    expect(expectedView.exists()).toBeTruthy(); // test case passing

});
```

This test case is passing, however i wanted to testing this function in deep on using

```
  expectedView.html();
```

I'm getting the output as

```
  <expected-view-stub content="25 is the value" data="[object Object]" show="true"></expected-view-stub>
```

How can I test that expected View Content should have 25 in it ? I'm new to Vue test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.toMatch()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tomatchregexp--string) to match a string with a RegEx.

This should work:

```
expect(expectedView.html()).toMatch(/25/);
```